# Weird behaviour with window object when removing property from it

Tags: javascript

```
function foobar() {}

console.log(typeof window.foobar); // "function"
console.log(typeof window.alert); // "function"

delete window.foobar;
delete window.alert;

console.log(typeof window.foobar); // "function"
console.log(typeof window.alert); // "undefined"

console.log(window.hasOwnProperty('foobar')); // true
console.log(window.hasOwnProperty('alert')); // false
```

Can somebody please explain, how this is possible?

Why can't I simply delete the `foobar` property of the window object?

Why is a custom global function like `foobar` protected against `delete` operator, but a built-in global function like `alert` not?

Comment: Global symbols are created such that the `configurable` property flag is set to `false`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Global variables are not configurable:

```js
Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(window, 'foobar').configurable; // false
```

That's because according to [Static Semantics: TopLevelVarDeclaredNames](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-block-static-semantics-toplevelvardeclarednames), function declarations are like `var` declarations:

> At the top level of a function or script, inner function declarations
>   are treated like var declarations.

And [Runtime Semantics: GlobalDeclarationInstantiation](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-globaldeclarationinstantiation) declares them as non-configurable:

> 16. For each production *f* in *functionsToInitialize*, do
>
>     3. Let *status* be *envRec*.[CreateGlobalFunctionBinding](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-createglobalfunctionbinding)(*fn*, *fo*, **false**).

[CreateGlobalFunctionBinding (N, V, D)](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-createglobalfunctionbinding) uses the argument **false** as the configurability of the property:

> 6. 1. Let *desc* be the PropertyDescriptor{[[Value]]:*V*, [[Writable]]: **true**, [[Enumerable]]: **true** , [[Configurable]]:
>         *D*}.

Therefore, the [[[Delete]]](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-ordinary-object-internal-methods-and-internal-slots-delete-p) internal method, used by the [`delete` operator](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-delete-operator-runtime-semantics-evaluation), won't succeed:

> 5. If *desc*.[[Configurable]] is **true**, then
>
>    1. Remove the own property with name *P* from *O*.
>    2. Return **true**.
> 6. Return **false**.

That's why you should use strict mode. Otherwise some problems are silently ignored.

```js
delete window.foobar; // false (in sloppy mode)
delete window.foobar; // TypeError (in strict mode)
```

You can delete the native `alert` because it's configurable.

That method is defined in the [HTML spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/browsers.html#the-window-object) as an IDL method:

> ```
> [Global]
> /*sealed*/ interface Window : EventTarget {
>   // ...
>   void alert(optional DOMString message = "");
> };
> ```

According to WebIDL, [exposed operations](http://heycam.github.io/webidl/#es-operations) should be configurable if they don't are [unforgeable](http://heycam.github.io/webidl/#dfn-unforgeable-on-an-interface):

> The property has attributes { [[Writable]]: *B*, [[Enumerable]]:
>   **true**, [[Configurable]]: *B* }, where *B* is **false** if the operation is [unforgeable](http://heycam.github.io/webidl/#dfn-unforgeable-on-an-interface) on the interface, and **true**
>   otherwise.

```
Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(window, 'alert').configurable; // true
```

If you want to be able to delete the function, assign it as a property instead of using a function declaration:

```
window.foobar = function() {};
Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(window, 'foobar').configurable; // true
delete window.foobar; // true
```

That's because when you create a property via a property assignment, it's configurable. From [CreateDataProperty](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-createdataproperty), used by the [[[Set]] internal method](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-ordinary-object-internal-methods-and-internal-slots-set-p-v-receiver),

> 3. Let *newDesc* be the PropertyDescriptor{[[Value]]: *V*, [[Writable]]: **true**, [[Enumerable]]: **true**, [[Configurable]]:
>      **true**}.

Comment: This is what I saw too; it's written down explicitly somewhere I guess?

Comment: Great answer, thank you! Is there a way to change that `configurable` object descriptor? I tried `Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(window, 'alert').configurable = false;` and hoped it does something..

Comment: I am also aware of benefits of `strict mode`. It's most of the time pain in the ass, but just for good reasons. :)

Comment: @Pointy I think it's defined in [CreateGlobalFunctionBinding(N, V, D)](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-createglobalfunctionbinding), where the configurability D is false from [Runtime Semantics: GlobalDeclarationInstantiation](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-globaldeclarationinstantiation)

Comment: @Oriol ah OK thanks!! It makes solid sense of course.

Comment: @K.Güler— *alert* is a host provided function, it's not part of ECMAScript, so not covered by the standard and therefore implementations can do what they like with it (such as make it not configurable if they wish). However, if the *de facto* standard is for it to be configurable, then making it not configurable might "break the web".

Comment: @RobG I see. I can imagine what a mess it could make then.. :D

Comment: @Oriol what is exactly the difference between assigning the `foobar` function as property to the `window` object rather than declaring it as function in the first place? I mean, if you declare something in the global scope, it automatically gets property of the global `window` object. So it ends up all  the same. But still I only can delete the explicitly declared `window` property..

Comment: @K.Güler That's because property assignments create configurable properties.

Comment: @Oriol Ah, I see. That makes sense. Many thanks for your detailed information!